# Notation: $\mathrm{ord}_a(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, notation

I'm familiar with the notation $\mathrm{ord}_a(x)$, when $x$ is an integer.  However, I'm reading a book where this notation is used with $x$ rational.  I'm not sure how to interpret this?

Comment: If it refers to the multiplicative order, reduce x mod a.

Comment: The situation is x is rational, 2x is an integer and p is an odd prime.  The book says that it is clear that ord_p(x)=>0.  Do you know what this means?

Comment: In this situation, $x$ can be written as $\frac{m}{2}$. Then, for any odd prime $p$, only the numerator can contribute to the order, i.e. if $m=p^rm'$ where $m'$ is relatively prime to $p$, then, $ord_p(x)=r\geq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is defined and explained in some detail [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400intro.pdf): see pages 11-13.

Comment: +1. Could you please explain why, as far as I understand, there are two different notations for, what seems to me, the same concept? I mean the $p-$ adic valuation of the rational number $p/q$: $\nu_p(p/q).$

Comment: @Américo: yes, these are two different notations for the same concept.  It is reasonable to write it as $v_p$ because it is is a discrete **v**aluation.  It is also traditional to refer to the exponent of $p$ in the factorization of $\frac{a}{b}$ as the "order at $p$ of $\frac{a}{b}$'', which makes the $\operatorname{ord}_p$ notation reasonable.  (I myself use both.)  For better or worse, having multiple notations for the same thing is pretty common in mathematics...

Comment: Thanks! It confirms my understanding. I have used $\nu$ instead of $v$ because I see that notation many times.

Answer (score 5):

For any rational number $x$ and any prime integer $p$, we can write $x=p^r\frac{m}{n}$ uniquely (where $r$ is an integer thanks to Yuval for clarifying that), where $m,n$ are integers relatively prime to $p$. Then, we write $ord_p(x)=r$

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question.

Comment: Just to clarify: $r$ is an integer that could be negative, e.g. $\mathrm{ord}_p(1/p) = -1$.